# Can a game like Minecraft be built using .NET/Mono instead of Java?

Tags: java, .net

I was wondering if such game can be built with .NET/Mono instead of using Java. Of course, the author had his reasons for using Java but if he knew only .NET could he build a game identical to that one in terms of graphics, speed, cross platform compatibility, etc.

What are the big advantages of using Java or .NET/Mono for such purposes ?

Comment: You may wish to ask this over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Cross platform compatibility, sure if you want to use .Net 2.x....

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, however these kind of questions aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: wrong. Mono supports all of .net 3.5 and most of .net4 if not all. It doesn't support XNA, WPF, and similar libraries, but that's not part of the C# spec. They're additional proprietary libraries.

Comment: @Joel Hm ok, guess that was the Mono plugin that was still stuck on 2.x then (actually I never managed to get any silverlight thing running here). I stand corrected then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he could.

A big advantage would be the [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791) game development studio and all of the community behind it.

A disadvantage is that mono doesn't support this (there is a project Olive by the mono guys, but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I'm writing a client in C++, and I think the biggest slowdown is the graphics, particularly the graphics driver.  Java isn't a big slowdown, because most of the slowness is outside of the program if you're doing it right.

For .NET, I expect you could use DirectX more easily.

The main upside with Java is that Minecraft can be run inside a web browser, and on Linux and Apple with almost no porting effort.